# ¿Cómo enviar un array con muchos elementos por NuSOAP?

Tags: php, array, webservice, diseño

De momento, tenemos un servicio web que envía un arreglo con la información. Pero el array se arma con la data de diferentes bases de datos, con un mínimo de 500.000 registros, y con una estructura multidimensional dinámica. ¿Cómo puedo enviar un array de tamaño considerable con NuSOAP en el request? ¿Existe posiblidad alguna? ¿O debería optar por otra vía como?

Más a detalle. Estamos desarrollando un proyecto, donde desde nuestro server se inician contactos directos con hosts clientes, a traves de webservices. En un punto, se necesitan traer desde los clientes, ciertas tablas de algunas bases de datos, los cuales pueden llegar a pesar desde 1MB hasta mas de 500MB (pocos casos). El punto es, cómo manejar esta data. ¿Pasandola en el request? ¿cURL? ¿Armando un fichero temporal en el host cliente y copiando desde nuestro servidor? Teniendo en cuenta que son contactos diarios, en una cantidad de usuarios que va a ir incrementando, quedamos parados aca con la duda.

Conexiones remotas a las DB de los clientes, no nos interesa por el hecho de no querer manejar info de acceso muy sensible. Además de que todo depende de las políticas de cada prestador de servicios que manejen. Si no, la última opción sería dejar alojados estos archivos en el mismo host de cada uno, pero, habría que ver el espacio libre en cada caso, y armar alguna función para depurar cada X tiempo cosa de no llenarlos.

Comment: Con semejante volumen de datos sería interesante analizar si sale a cuenta aplicar algún algoritmo de compresión para minimizar el volumen a mover

Comment: @eferion efectivamente, aunque como dije, es muy aleatorio. Puede tocar una de gran volúmen, entre muchas de 2MB.

Lo que más nos preocupa y tiene parados, es esto, como encarar. 
Enviar todo el array por webservice (lo cual no logramos), almacenar en server local, generar un temporal en el loca, y copiar el archivo desde nuestro host remotamente aunque también seria inestable...

Comment: El webservice no tiene por qué enviar todo de golpe. Puede paginar los resultados. Por otro lado el webservice puede tomar la decisión de compactar los resultados si el número de registros excede de cierto valor. Creo que la mejor estrategia si no tenéis muy claros los límites es empezar con decisiones sencillas y posteriormente ir puliendo el sistema

Comment: @eferion el tema es que por cada usuario, el numero de bases de datos, y de tablas por cada una, como a su vez las filas que contienen, son absolutamente arbitrarios. 

Es mas que complejo.

Comment: No tiene por qué serlo. Si vais a enviar los datos se supone que el receptor sabe interpretar esas diferencias... A la red le va a dar igual lo que envíes y entiendo que salvo por el problema de empaquetar los datos el resto del sistema ya está funcionando

Comment: Estuvimos chequeando, generando un archivo temporal en el server del cliente, variando el peso del archivo, pero, como dije al principio, fluctúa mucho según lo que contenga cada cliente.

En varios casos da como resultado 504 Gateway Time-out, aunque por detrás continúa corriendo hasta acabar correctamente.

Así que estamos evaluando esto ahora...